# CParseError when extracting data after Submitting form (Python)

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to access the "Yield Curve Data" available on [this page](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/interest-rates/bond-yield-curves/). It has a radio button which upon clicking "Submit" results in a CSV File, from which I am looking to get the data. I am looking to get the data from the "Retrieve all data" Option. I want to convert this data into a `dataframe`. My code is as follows and I receive the Error `CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 11, saw 2` in the line `df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)` and am unable to understand how to resolve this.

```
import urllib, urllib2
import csv
import StringIO
import pandas as pd

my_url = 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/interest-rates/bond-yield-curves/'
data = urllib.urlencode({'lastchange': 'all'}) 
request = urllib2.Request(my_url, data)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)

text = result.read()

csvfile = StringIO.StringIO(text)
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile) #Error!
print df
```

Thank You